# Refreshing Formik Form after useMutation (Apollo Client) in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, formik

I am building my front-end in React. An "edit profile" page performs a useQuery to get the information from a database, displays a form using Formik and a useMutation to perform the update. Unfortunately, the Formik form does not inherently accept new input after the mutation. My current solution is to "refetchQueries", which does address my needs.

The useMutation returns the entire updated profile, which is in the handleSubmit function. I was hoping to feed the results into new initial values for Formik. The difference is I would save myself a query. If this is possible, can someone please help me on a conceptual level?

Comment: conceptually it is possible with `enableReinitialize` and some formik API functions, search for examples within formik issues